# Add Multiple values to ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

Is there a shorter way to add all the numbers from 1-100 into a combobox in c#? Currently the method i am aware of is to add 1 by 1 manually and that consumes time. Is there a faster way to do it?

P.S I am very new to c#, so if you could kindly explain your code to me that would be very helpful. :D

Comment: @PeterB I think they meant that typing out `ComboBox.Items.Add(1)`, `ComboBox.Items.Add(2)` etc is time consuming

Comment: @PeterB ComboBoc.Items.Add(1) is really time consuming for large numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you should create an array containing 1-100. This can be done like so

```
int[] list = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

After this you need to add them all at once with `AddRange()`

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(list);
```

This code will add 1-100 to your comboBox

To use this code you need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your document

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Badiparmagi for correcting me on adding the values to the comboBox

Comment: **int[]** can not be added to ComboBox like this. you should cast it to **object[]** like this: 
 `var list =  Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Cast<object>().ToArray();`

Comment: `comboBox1.DataSource = list;` should also work just fine

Comment: Thank you that helped me :D

Answer (score 3):

This question has already been answered by Alfie Goodacre and is an efficient way to add multiple items to a combobox with little code, but for people new to c# or programming in general, the simplest way to add numerous numbers to a combobox would be a single for loop as follows, wouldn't it?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
}
```

The integer variable "i" starts at 1 and increments by one. As long as it's lower or equal to 100, its value will be added as an item to the combobox.